# Not able to bind checked checkboxes for update

Tags: angular, checkbox

[Component .ts file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZgqb.png)

[HTML File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fp0zF.png)

[Console Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hiqoc.png)

Comment: Read this: [ask]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.